# OnTriggerEnter2D too slow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

**To Start:** I am relatively new to c# & these posts, though I have had experience in coding in general.
**The Premise:** Following the advice of "make what you want to make" I am working on a procedurally generated dungeon thingy. Basically, when you transition into a room I need to find the ID of the room you are entering (I have a jagged array database of all rooms). while I tried many-a-things I eventually landed on having the GameObject that the world creation code is one zip around to a specific spot in each room (each room essentially fits into a larger grid) resulting in my using OnTriggerEnter2D as a function that returns a room's RoomID. Example:

```
    RoomID = -1;

        transform.position += Vector3.up * 14;
        Debug.Log(RoomID + " after going up");
        if (RoomID == -1) { TopConnectedRoom = false; } else { TopConnectedRoom = true; }
        transform.position += Vector3.down * 14;
        RoomID = -1;
```

**The Problem:** Because OnTriggerEnter2D works of of physics, therefore works off of FixedUpdate()/physics time, it ends up triggering too slow (I can verify this thanks to a number of Debug.Log()s that tell me the value of RoomID and the value from the actual OnTriggerEnter always appears last). I've been stumped on this for a long while though this method of finding the RoomID is the only one that as yielded some sort of result.

Heres the OnTriggerEnter2D in case y'all want that:

```
    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Room")
        {
            string RoomName = other.name;
            string RoomIDString;
            Debug.Log(RoomName.Length + " room length " + RoomName);
            if (RoomName.Length >= 5) {
                int n;
                bool isNumber = int.TryParse(RoomName.Substring(4, 2), out n);
                if (isNumber) { RoomIDString = RoomName.Substring(4, 2); }
                else { RoomIDString = RoomName.Substring(4, 1); }
            } else { RoomIDString = RoomName.Substring(4, 1); }
            RoomID = int.Parse(RoomIDString);
            Debug.Log(RoomID + " from OnTriggerEnter2D");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're handling your rooms as mere 2D colliders with some coded names. Not only does that make you dependant of the physics engine, whose speed you have no way to improve except by giving it less work, but that makes the simple business of finding a room a complicated exercise of juggling with bits of strings. Things are only likely to go downhill if you add more code on top of that. I suggest you rethink your design to implement some kind of coordinates system (e.g. a grid-based dungeon) and a room handling module that does not get so hopelessly entangled with the Unity engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the [Default Solver Iterations](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/class-PhysicsManager.html)

Comment: Looks like the "Default Solver Iterations" is no longer in the unity software and was broken up into "Velocity Iterations" and "Position Iterations." additionally I tried up-ing Position Iteration all the way up to 200 though it just caused an excessive amount of lag as well as not working.